# Dynamic Custom Fields for Data Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in the process of creating a dynamic database where user will be able to create resource type where he/she can add custom fields (multiple texts, strings, and files)

Each resource type will have the ability to display, import, export its data;

I've been thinking about it and here are my approaches.  I would love to hear what do you guys think.

Ideas:

1. just hashing all the custom data in a data field (pro: writing is easier, con: reading back out may be harder);
2. children fields (the model will have multiple fields of strings, fields of text, and fields for file path);
3. fixed number of custom fields in the same table with a key mapping data hash stored in the same row;
4. Non-SQL approach, but then the problem would be generating/changing models on the fly to work with different custom fields;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you can create few models:
- StringData
- BooleanData
- TextData
- FileData
etc (all data and fields formats you need)

Each model will refferenced to some project, wich will contain information about fields

IE:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_fields
  has_many :string_datas :through => project_fields
  has_many :file_datas :through => project_fields
  has_many :boolean_datas :through => project_fields
  etc ...
end

class ProjectField < ActiveRecord::Base
  # title:string field_type:string project_id:integer name:string
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :string_datas
  has_many :file_datas
  has_many :boolean_datas
  etc ...
end

class StringData < ActiveRecord::Base
  # data:string project_field_id:integer
  belongs_to :project_field, :conditions => { :field_type => 'String' }
end

class FileData < ActiveRecord::Base
  # data:file project_field_id:integer
  belongs_to :project_field, :conditions => { :field_type => 'File' }
end

project = Project.new
project.project_fields.new(:title => "Product title", :field_type => "String", :name => 'product_title')
project.project_fields.new(:title => "Product photo", :field_type => "File", :name => 'product_photo')
project.save

<% form_for project do |f| -%>
  <% project.project_fields.each do |field| -%>
    <%= field_setter field %>
    #=> field_setter is a helper method wich creates form element (text_field, text_area, file_field etc) for each type of prject_field
    #=> ie: if field.field_type == 'String' it will return
    #=> text_field_tag field.name => <input name='product_name' />
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

And create (update) method

```
def create
  project = Project.new(params[:project])
  project.project_fields.each do |field|
    filed.set_field params[field.name]
    # where set_field is model method for setting value depending on field type
  end
  project.save
end
```

It is not tested and optimized but it just showing the way you can implement it.

UPDATE: I've updated code but It's only model, you have to think yourself a little :) and you can try to find out another implementation

Comment: How do I query these custom fields when we need to pass in some conditions?

Comment: I've updated my answer. But it is quite big problem to write in one comment. So try to realize your implementation looking on this code

Comment: Thanks for all the inspiration.  I tested a bit on the MongoDB approach and I think I am staying with a similar implementation of yours.  I am still a bit not sure how slow would the querying be.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a model for DynamicField?

Columns:

```
  t.integer :dynamic_field_owner_id
  t.string :dynamic_field_owner_type
  t.string :name, :null => false
  t.string :value
  t.string :value_type_conversion, :default => 'to_s'
  # any additional fields from paperclip, has_attachment, etc.
  t.timestamps
```

model class:

```
class DynamicField > ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :dynamic_field_owner, :polymorphic => true

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_inclusion_of :value_type_conversion, :in => %w(to_s to_i to_f)
  validates :value_or_attachment

  def value
    read_attribute(:value).send(value_type_conversion)
  end

 private

 def value_or_attachment
   unless value? || file?
     errors.add_to_base('Must have either value or file')
   end
 end

end
```